# Making classes work together in obj-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm writing a program for iPhone that will first let the user take a photo, then will dynamically retrieve a colour of the place where the user taps on the image, and draw a rectangle of that colour. I have two relevant classes for this: `AppViewController` and `AppView`. The former contains all the UI elements and IBActions, the latter the position of last tap, the touches-handling methods and the `drawRect` (and a static method to get colour data at a given coords of an image).

What I wanted to do is to put the touch-handling (calling `drawRect` in `touchesMoved`/`Ended`) and the `drawRect` in the `AppViewController`. That doesn't work, since that class doesn't inherit from `UIView`, but from `UIViewController`. What's the correct way to do that?

Another way to phrase that: How to constantly change something (well, constantly as long as the user is swiping across the screen) in a class that doesn't support touch-detection methods?

(This probably doesn't explain it well. Please ask clarifying questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [delegate pattern](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html) might be helpful to you in this situation. You could call your delegate's shouldUpdateRectangle selector in touchesMoved/Ended.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a correct way to move the view's behaviors into a view controller, since that is not the way the classes are meant to be used. You should probably look at what's driving you to try to subvert the framework's design this way, because that is likely going to be easier to fix.

It's not uncommon, though, for a view to call out to a supporting class for help in this stuff. You could certainly have your view's `drawRect:` call methods in the view controller, though I would be careful about mixing their concerns too much, because it could get hard to figure out who's responsible for what.